# Dark red messages in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm getting these weird dark red messages in Sublime Text after installing Sierra iOS and updating Sublime to Build 3126.

[image: Sublime Text inline errors screenshot]

I tried to delete the pieces of code and retype them by hand, but they keep reappearing every time I hit 'Save'.  Does anyone know what they are and how to get rid of them, please?

Answer (score 18):

Those are *inline build errors*. It is a new feature in the [Beta Build 3124](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-build-3124) ([Dev Build 3118](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-3118/21270)).

> Build errors are now shown inline, at the location the error occurred. This is done via the new Phantoms API, which allows HTML annotations to be added to the text buffer by plugins.
>
> [image]
>
> Inline build errors can be disabled via the `show_errors_inline` setting.
>
> — [Sublime Text Blog](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-build-3124)

Inline build errors can be disabled via the `show_errors_inline` setting.

**User**

`Menu > Preferences > Settings` (`Preferences.sublime-settings - User`)

```
{
    "show_errors_inline": false
}
```

**Per-Project**

`Menu > Project > Edit Project`

```
{
    "settings": {
        "show_errors_inline": false
    }
}
```

## How to Dismiss Inline Build Errors via Key Binding

Create a custom key binding.

`Menu > Preferences > Key Bindings`

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+l"],
    "command": "exec",
    "args": {
        "hide_phantoms_only": true
    }
}
```

Or for vim modes:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+l"],
    "command": "exec",
    "args": {
        "hide_phantoms_only": true
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode" }
    ]
}
```

Re: [Sublime Text Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/keyboard-binding-to-dismiss-inline-build-errors/21956/6)

Comment: Thank you so much, Gerard!  Now I understand what they are -- will be looking for my code errors.  Thanks again!