# sublime showing file name on each line after save

Tags: javascript, web, sublimetext3

After I save, there's a little pop up that shows the file name of what im working on. It's pretty frustrating to keep removing it after each time i save. [image: after i Save]

Comment: Did you recently install a new Sublime plugin?

Comment: Not recently. But i do have auto-update.

Comment: It's linting. Do you also see errors from the JSLint plugin at the bottom of your window?

Comment: I initially thought it was linting but i dont see any errors

Comment: Linting doesn't look for errors, it looks for absolutely anything that doesn't fit it's very narrow standards heh. Spacing, use of increment/decrement operators, etc etc will all be flagged. It doesn't need to have any actual syntactic errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714095/dark-red-messages-in-sublime

Answer (score 4):

it is probably caused by JSLint Package for sublime.
try to disable it in sublime

- (command + shift + p on mac)
- then type "disable package" then
- type "JSLint"

Answer (score 1):

These are the new inline errors introduced in Sublime Text Build 3124 (and Developer Build 3118), they usually indicate there's something wrong in your code.

If you think you have to, you can disable them entirely by setting `show_errors_inline` to false.