# Sublime text 3 how to hide Definition on mouse over function?

Tags: sublimetext3

I've tried to find a solution in other posts but no solution found.

I'm using Sublime text 3 and since I installed last update 3126, when I put my mouse over a function, in PHP ou Javascript, I get a list of all files using this function and it's useless for me and takes all place on my screen.

How can I hide this ?

[image: Sublime Text 3 Definition mouse over function]

I'm using those Packages :

- alignment
- compare side by side
- Emmet
- minifier
- Sidebar
- livereload
- SFTP
- Sublimelinter
- colorpicker

I love this tool but I need a bit more help to configure my own options.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Also new in 3124 is Show Definition, which will show where a symbol is defined when hovering over it with the mouse. This makes use of the new `on_hover` API, and can be controlled via the `show_definitions` setting. — [Sublime Text Blog](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-build-3124)

Show definitions on hovers can be disabled via the `show_definitions` setting.

**User**

`Menu > Preferences > Settings` (`Preferences.sublime-settings - User`)

```
{
    "show_definitions": false
}
```

**Per-Project**

`Menu > Project > Edit Project`

```
{
    "settings": {
        "show_definitions": false
    }
}
```

Similar to [this SO question on inline build errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714095/dark-red-messages-in-sublime/39714352#39714352).