# Sublime showing full file path on every line while saving any file

Tags: sublimetext3

I have updated my sublime text.Now whenever i am trying to save any file in editor it shows full file path at every line.

[image]

don't know how to disable this

Comment: https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-build-3124

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dark red messages in Sublime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714095/dark-red-messages-in-sublime)